# Show login Screen when hitting Homebutton

Tags: ios, swift

i have a Swift Project wich needs to switch back to Login Viewcontroller when the user hits the Homebutton or the Appswitcher (like most Bankingapps or 1Password does). The Login Viewcontroller is the initial VC. I searched for that since a few days, but couldn't find any Information about that. How do i implement that in my project?

Thank you

Dirk

Comment: subscribe to `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and invoke the `–popToRootViewControllerAnimated` method when you receive such notification.

Comment: @holex - shouldn't that be `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`? "An app is active when it is receiving events. An active app can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains focus when the device is unlocked." If the OP want's to go back on *leaving* the application not upon entering it I think that notification is better suited. (1PW "locks" on leaving or even on receiving a notification)

Comment: yes, indeed, I pasted the wrong one. :)

Comment: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification will not be invoked when user double taps home for the Appswitcher. Is there a way to check for "will enter Background" or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying a little on @holex and my comments (and working without notifications)
this solution would require your navigation to be based on a `UINavigationController` with your Login ViewController set as `rootViewController`.

**EDIT**: To ensure your app is using a `UINavigationController` as described above:

- open your `Main.Storyboard`
- if you see a layout like this you're already set:
  [image: view layout in XCode]
- otherwise select your current root view controller
- from the menu choose *Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller*
- if you don't want the navigation bar visible, disable the *"Shows Navigation Bar"* option

**END OF EDIT**

In that constellation you could do something like this in your application delegate:

```
// will get called just before the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification is posted
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if let keyWindow = application.keyWindow,
               navVC = keyWindow.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        navVC.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

This forces a pop-to-root whenever the app looses focus.
To cite from the apple docs:

> [the app] loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked,

Using the application switcher or pressing the home button both should count in that category.

I placed a sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Shirk/LockscreenDemo)

Comment: Thank you very much, but my App never gets inside that if. So it's no doing anything for me. Do i have to declare the rootviewcontroller somehow?

Comment: @DirkHildebrand - I could provide a better sample if you could tell me if your application uses storyboards or does all setup in code etc.

Comment: OK, updating my explanation and pushing a sample project to github

Comment: I hope now it's clear enough. To me it sound's you don't have a navigation controller at your root - check out my sample application.

Comment: That did the trick: i didn't embed the initial Viewcontroller in the navigation controller, after doing so your Code works like a charm!! Thank you so much!